# Error while Configuring Decision Server to standalone profile IBM ODM 8.9.2 with WAS 8.5.5 JDK 1.7_64

Tags: websphere, ibm-odm

I'm trying to Augment Decision Server (IBM ODM 8.9.2) on WAS 8.5.5 with JDK 1.7_64 and getting error.

I'm setting up the JDK (we will be using default derby DB so no DB creation):

```
managesdk -listAvailable
managesdk.bat -setCommandDefault -sdkname 1.7_64
managesdk.bat -setNewProfileDefault -sdkname 1.7_64
```

Creating an application profile:

```
.\bin\manageprofiles.bat -create -profileName ODM01
-templatePath .\profileTemplates\default
-enableAdminSecurity true -adminUserName wasadmin -adminPassword wasadmin
```

Then trying to Augment the application server profile for Decision Server:

```
.\bin\manageprofiles.bat
-augment -profileName ODM01
-templatePath .\profileTemplates\odm\decisionserver\default
-odmHome C:\IBM\ODM892
-databaseConfigFile .\profileTemplates\odm\decisionserver\default\ derbyDBSampleSetting.properties

Error:- WASX7357I: By request, this scripting client is not connected to any server process. Certain configuration and application operations will be available in local mode.
WASX7303I: The following options are passed to the scripting environment and are available as arguments that are stored in the argv variable: "[C:/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profileTemplates/odm/decisionserver/default/actions/scripts, C:/IBM/ODM892, server1]"
ERROR: Unable to load resource bundle! (com.ibm.ws.scripting.resources.messages)
!GBRPT0053I!
ERROR: Unable to load resource bundle! (com.ibm.ws.scripting.resources.messages)
!GBRPT0017I!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profileTemplates\odm\decisionserver\default\actions\scripts\decisionserverDeploymentHelper.py", line 93, in installXU
ra =  AdminConfig.installResourceAdapter(modulePath, nodeName, params)
com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
java.util.MissingResourceException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.ibm.rules.res.xu.messages bundle

ERROR: Unable to load resource bundle! (com.ibm.ws.scripting.resources.messages)
WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profileTemplates\odm\decisionserver\default\actions/scripts/installExecutionUnitAdapter.py"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException
java.util.MissingResourceException: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.ibm.rules.res.xu.messages bundle
```

Why isn't it able to connect to any server process?

Comment: Did you make a cut-n-paste error, or is there a space in the db template properties file name:.\decisionserver\default\ derbyDBSampleSetting.properties

Comment: Also IBM Knowledge Center topic https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSQP76_8.9.1/com.ibm.odm.distrib.config.was/config_ds_res_was/tsk_was_deploy_xu.html discusses correcting the missing resource bundle error, that may make the real error more apparent.

Comment: Space in front of DerbyDB is copy paste error, as suggested I tried installing XU RAR but im getting error:- com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.ws.scripting.ScriptingException: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConfigServiceException: ADMG0304E: There is another J2C Resource Adapter with the same archive path that has inconsistent Isolated Class Loader attribute.

Comment: To resolve the ADMG0304E, remove the XU Resource Adapter (you can use the admin console or wsadmin) and save the config, then rerun augmentation.  You should look at the technote to resolve the missing resource bundle